# Generate all the public functions of certain PHP class in plain text?

Tags: php

I have a php class for eg:

```
class test {
     public function newTest(){
          $this->bigTest();
          $this->smallTest();
     }

     private function bigTest(){
          //Big Test Here
     }

     private function smallTest(){
          //Small Test Here
     }

     public function scoreTest(){
          //Scoring code here;
     }
}
```

Now, is there any possiblility of getting the functions of class test as below in plain text file for eg like test_functions.txt or any

```
test/newTest
test/bigTest
test/smallTest
test/scoreTest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_class_methods](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) to do this:

```
<?php
class test {
     public function newTest(){
      $this->bigTest();
      $this->smallTest();
     }

     private function bigTest(){
      //Big Test Here
     }

     private function smallTest(){
      //Small Test Here
     }

     public function scoreTest(){
      //Scoring code here;
     }

     public function showMe(){
      echo 'Class Name: test - inside object';
      $class_methods = get_class_methods($this);
      print_r($class_methods);
     }
}

    $class_methods = get_class_methods('test');
    echo 'Class Name: test - outside object';
    print_r($class_methods);

    $test=new test();
    $test->showMe();

?>
```

This will however only have access to public functions if called from outside the object. You can however call it perfectly well inside the object itself.

Output:

```
Class Name: test - outside objectArray
(
    [0] => newTest
    [1] => scoreTest
    [2] => showMe
)
Class Name: test - inside objectArray
(
    [0] => newTest
    [1] => bigTest
    [2] => smallTest
    [3] => scoreTest
    [4] => showMe
)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I was planing to generate all the public funtions of lost of class that exist in different folder a lot like 100 with one php. folder structure: test/controller/test.php.